# Keep helm from picking up symbol at point

Tags: helm

[`helm`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) seems to implicitly insert the current symbol at point as an initial query.

[image]

(For reference, this is `helm-omni` from [here](https://github.com/PythonNut/emacs-config/blob/dev/modules/config-helm.el#L142-L225))

Note how the minibuffer is empty, yet helm is already searching for `idle-require`.

This has some performance implications that I'd like to avoid. Is there any way I can turn this behavior off?

(Probably will require advice, as Helm's author says he doesn't want to add an option to turn it off).

There has been a lot of interest in this (but nothing's come of it yet):

- [helm #648](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/648)
- [helm #658](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/658)
- [helm #876](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/876)

Comment: The screenshot looks a bit like `swiper`, which doesn't have the deficiency that you mention. And `lispy-goto` works better than `imenu` for Elisp.

Comment: @abo-abo Indeed. But it's called `helm-omni` for a reason. It does everything: files, buffers, lines, ag, find, locate, git etc.. The function automatically builds the helm based on context information (i.e. am I in a project?). It works _really_ well... except when the ffap-like behavior jumps up and gets in the way.

Comment: I see. No wonder you try to make it work:)

Comment: You should probably link to the definition of helm-omni from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284509/821010 or wherever in the question... although with that version of `my-helm-omni` I'm not able to reproduce the issue you described.

Comment: @JoeCorneli ah thanks. It didn't occur to me that this could be function specific. It _looks_ like this has something to do with `helm-source-find-files`, which is in my latest omni, but not that one.

Comment: I think it is a very useful feature of helm, you can often get what you want once you launch helm. The `helm-sources-using-default-as-input` user option might be useful if you want to choose what helm sources can use this feature.

Comment: @xuchunyang yes, it is. But `helm-omni` can have a lot of sources, and at least a few of them are slow out-of-process sources (ag, git, locate, find). Unfortunately, the default input is not done async, so it delays the entire helm until all of the processes have started, which can make it unusably slow. Without default input, the sources spool up in the background if needed, and the whole thing is fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sources used by you like `helm-source-imenu` and `helm-source-occur` are in the `helm-sources-using-default-as-input` list, so `helm` will build result initially, so setting that list to nil temporarily should work, for example

```
(let ((helm-sources-using-default-as-input nil))
  (helm ...))
```